# Checking Each Element in an Array to See if it is equal to a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string-comparison

I have a number of elements in an array, I would like to check if a string is equal to any of these elements in the array. The number of elements in the array can change in number.

I have counted the number of elements in the array hoping to get somewhat of an advantage but haven't been able to come up with a solution.

```cs
int ArrayCount = FinalEncryptText.Count();
```

```cs
foreach (string i in FinalEncryptText)
                {
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the foreach implementation you have provided, you could include an if condition with `String.Equals(string)` - as [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512161/10627707) pointed out earlier.

But it's worth noting that `String.Equals(string)` without additional arguments is equivalent to using the `==` operator. So it's better if you specify the `StringComparison` type so that you express what kind of comparison you wish to perform.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (string element in myStringArray)
{
   if(element.Equals("foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     ...
}
```

You could even include the evaluation as a predicate in a LINQ query. For example, let's say you wanted to see which strings passed the evaluation:

```
var matches = myStringArray
      .Where(element => element.Equals("foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You can read more about comparing strings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings).

Comment: A more in depth version is [How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings).

Comment: That is indeed better Erik, I've updated my previous link with your link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String.Equals method in an if statement. More info on String.Method here: [String.Equals Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8).

```
if(firstString.Equals(secondString))
{
    //whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's may last resort solution, thanks though :)

Comment: What do you mean its your last resort solution?  What kind of solution are you looking for then?

Comment: I found a solution man, sorry I wasn't specific. I tried to be as descriptive as possible. I needed to make a variable which was an integer and increase it over and over until.. blah blah blah anyways I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your method looks like, but I'm assuming..  you're given a random array of strings.. and you want to find a certain element in that array. Using a foreach loop:

```
public string Check(string[] FinalEncryptText)
{
    foreach (string i in FinalEncryptText)
    {
       //let's say the word you want to match in that array is "whatever"
        if (i == "whatever")
        {
             return "Found the match: " + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Using a regular for loop:

```
public string Check(string[] FinalEncryptText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FinalEncryptText.Count; i++)
    {
       //let's say the word you want to match in that array is "whatever"
        if (FinalEncryptText[i] == "whatever")
        {
             //Do Something
             return "Found the match: " + FinalEncryptText[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you already have a fixed array.. and you're passing in a string to check if that string exists in the array then it would go something like this:

```
public string Check(string stringToMatch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FinalEncryptText.Count; i++)
    {
       //this will match whatever string you pass into the parameter
        if (FinalEncryptText[i] == stringToMatch)
        {
             //Do Something
             return "Found the match: " + FinalEncryptText[i];
        }
    }
}
```